# How to Html Input value echo in php

Tags: php, html, css

I have made some classes in css and i have a html form and i also have some html elements and i want to echo them by php but i want them to echo by the value of html form submition 
For eg

```
    <form action="index.php"  method="post">
<select name="slideNumber">
 <option value="3" name="slideNumber">3 Image Slider</option>
<option value="right-3" name="slideNumber">3 Image Right Slider</option>
<option value="4" name="slideNumber">4 Image Slider</option>
<option value="right-4" name="slideNumber">4 Image Right Slider</option>
<!--And more just like this-->
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php 
 $i= trim($_POST['slideNumber']);
if(($i = '3') || ($i = 'right-3')){
     $x= '3';
}
else if(($i = '4') || ($i = 'right-4')){
     $x= '4';
}
echo "
         <div class=\"slider-".$x."\">
         </div>
";
?>
```

It is showing only first $x 
I mean it is showing slider-3 even if i had give the value 4 in form please help me to solve this

Comment: use `==` instead of `=` to check for equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem is with equality check i.e your if condition

use:

```
if ($i === '3' || $i === 'right-3'){
   $x = '3';
} elseif ($i === '4' || $i === 'right-4)) {
   $x = '4';
}
```

Comment: Ohk i will try and will comment here what i got

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, You should check value of POST data by isset first...

```
if (isset($_POST['slideNumber']))
{}
```